# How do I add the explorer to GraphiQL using 'flask-graphql'?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, graphql

I am serving GraphiQL using `flask-graphql` but do not see any way to enable GraphiQL's "explorer" without using Node.JS. Is there a way to enable the explorer for a Python (`flask-graphql`) backend?

Answer (score 3):

Node.js is not required, but React *is* since both `graphiql` and `graphiql-explorer` are React components. `flask-graphql` just renders an HTML page with a script that renders the GraphiQL interface using React as shown [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/flask-graphql/blob/23fb85c6c8067c557b934c5f1d5f09eee80fa64e/flask_graphql/render_graphiql.py).

You should be able to provide your own template for rendering this page when creating your GraphQLView via the `graphiql_template` option as shown [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/flask-graphql).

Copy and paste the existing template, then add the script tag for the library:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/graphiql-explorer@0.4.6/graphiqlExplorer.min.js"></script>
```

And implement the component as shown [here](https://github.com/OneGraph/graphiql-explorer-example/blob/master/src/App.js). Since you're not transpiling this code, you won't be able to use JSX, so you'll need to do something like...

```
React.createElement(
  "div",
  { className: "graphiql-container" },
  React.createElement(
    GraphiQLExplorer,
    { /* props here */ },
  ),
  React.createElement(
    GraphiQL,
    { /* props here */ },
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked on the `flask-graphql` repo how to do it and I provided the initial template setup to get the explorer with some minor styles over that: [Enabling "explorer" at Flask-graphql](https://github.com/graphql-python/flask-graphql/issues/68#issuecomment-674427283).